# Include CSS and Javascript in specific Modx page

Tags: javascript, css, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to include a very simple snippet of CSS and JavaScript to a Modx page that lists recent newsletters from MailChimp:

```
<style type="text/css">
.display_archive {font-family: arial,verdana; font-size: 12px;}
.campaign {line-height: 125%; margin: 5px;}
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="//ZZZZ.us11.list-manage.com/generate-js/?u=XXXXX&fid=YYYYY&show=10" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `<script>` tag is returning a `document.write()` that outputs a list of links.

Unfortunately it looks like TinyMCE blocks `<style>` and `<script>` tags and this code is not being added. What is the best way to add this code chunk to a specific page?

I found [this](https://docs.modx.com/3.x/en/extending-modx/snippets/register-assets) page that shows ways to add code to the `<head>` or `<body>` tags, but I am looking to insert the code on a specific part of the page (since it does `document.write`, the placement is important.

I was thinking an alternative is to create a snippet that does:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://ZZZZZ.us11.list-manage.com/generate-js/?u=XXXXX&fid=YYYYY&show=10')
// remove "document.write"
// unescape slashes
return $clean_html;
```

But this does not seem like it would be the best method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your whole block in `<code></code>` tags.

```
<code>
    <style type="text/css">
        .display_archive {font-family: arial,verdana; font-size: 12px;}
        .campaign {line-height: 125%; margin: 5px;}
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" src="//ZZZZZ.us11.list-manage.com/generate-js/? 
    u=XXXXX&fid=YYYYY&show=10" type="text/javascript"></script>
</code>
```

Another option is to go into the TinyMCS config files and add `script` and `style` to the `extended_valid_elements`. Something like:

```
.AddSetting("extended_valid_elements", "script[*],style[*]")
```

Exactly how it's done (and whether possible) will depend on which TinyMCE plugin you're using. Some plugins allow for more configuration than others.

Another solution: (assuming the problem is you want to have editable rich text content before AND after the style and script tags) -- add two rich text boxes to the page template with the chunk containing your style and script tags in between them. For instance in the template you could have:

```
[[*content]]
[[$chunkWithTags]]
[[*anotherRichTextTV]]
```

Comment: The code is removed even when wrapped in `<code>` tags. Wouldnt adding script/style to `extended_valid_elements` pose a security issue?

Comment: I’ll leave the question regarding security to the experts, but I will say that getting TinyMCE to allow script tags is exactly what you are trying to do. So I see no difference between your stated goal and this solution to it.